# How do you Show tabbar after Signup or login iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Basically I have a tab based app which involves log in/ sign up from a landing page first before you can see the tabbar,I have literally been on this for about 3 hours with no solutions yet !

so its more like: 
LandingCtrl(tabBarNotvisible)-> LoginCtrl(tabBarNotvisible)-> profile(tabBarvisible)

This is what i tried:

appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    // Initialize tab controllers.  with each tab has its own navigation controller
    ProfileViewController *profileViewController =[[ProfileViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav1 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:profileViewController];
    [nav1 setTitle:@"Profile"];

    DiscoverViewController *discoverViewController=[[DiscoverViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav2 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:discoverViewController];
    [nav2 setTitle:@"Discover"];

    RecievedViewController *recievedViewController = [[RecievedViewController alloc]init];
    UINavigationController *nav3 = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:recievedViewController];
    [nav3 setTitle:@"Recieved"];

    // initialize tabbarcontroller and set your viewcontrollers.
    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nav1,nav2,nav3, nil];

    // Inititalize Navigationcontroller and set root as tabbar.
    self.navBarController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.tabBarController];

    LandingViewController *landingviewcontroller = [[LandingViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:landingviewcontroller];
    nVC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:landingviewcontroller];
    nVC.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.204 green:0.286 blue:0.369 alpha:1];
    [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment:UIOffsetMake(-100.f, 0) forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    nVC.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    nVC.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

    [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController. view];
    [self.tabBarController presentViewController:nVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    //[self.window setRootViewController:nVC];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Still cant get the darn thing to work, i would really appreciate your help, thanks !!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am following below code. This is working for me, check it once. You should create Landing page first then after create this logic on landing page.

```
NewHomeView *home=[[NewHomeView alloc]initWithNibName:@"NewHomeView_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UIImage *imag=[UIImage imageNamed:@"profile40x40.png"];
        [home setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Home" image:imag tag:100]];

        BiographyView *biography= [[BiographyView alloc] initWithNibName:@"BiographyView_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UIImage *imag1=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Biography40x40.png"];
        [biography setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Biography" image:imag1 tag:101]];

        GalleryView *gallery = [[GalleryView alloc] initWithNibName:@"GalleryView_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UIImage *imag2=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Gallery40x40.png"];
        [gallery setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Gallery" image:imag2 tag:102]];

        VideosView *video = [[VideosView alloc] initWithNibName:@"VideosView_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UIImage *imag3=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Videos40x40.png"];
        [video setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Videos" image:imag3 tag:103]];


        MoviesView *movies = [[MoviesView alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoviesView_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UIImage *imag4=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Movies40x40.png"];
        [movies setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Movies" image:imag4 tag:104]];


        NewsView *news = [[NewsView alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewsView_iPad" bundle:nil];
        UIImage *imag5=[UIImage imageNamed:@"news40x40.png"];
        [news setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"News" image:imag5 tag:105]];

        tabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
        [tabController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:home, biography, gallery,video,movies,news, nil]];

      [self.navigationController pushViewController:tabController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in AppDelegate.m

```
if(user logged in){
     // show tab bar
    [self.window addSubview:self.tabBarController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
else {
    LandingViewController *landingviewcontroller = [[LandingViewController alloc] init];
    UINavigationController *nVC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:landingviewcontroller];
    nVC = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:landingviewcontroller];
    [self.window addSubview: nVC.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

When user logs in , save that in storage for app to go to if statement next time app is launched from scratch.

Havent compiled it.. but you get the idea

Comment: i also used your solution and it worked but how do i dismiss the tabbarcontroller when i am logging out ?

Comment: You will have to look at your view controller hierarchy and then show the login view controller possibly by popping all other controllers or dismissing them.