# Using UINavigationController pushViewController:animated: to push UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

The documentation for the `UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:` selector states that the view controller pushed onto the receiver's stack "[cannot be a tab bar controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#jumpTo_18)".

However, in the [AVPlayerDemo sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple, this exact technique is used. From the AVPlayerDemo:

```
// Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
[self.cachedAssetBrowser pushViewController:self->tabBarController animated:NO];
```

Here `cachedAssetBrowser` is a `UINavigationController` instance and `tabBarController` is a `UITabBarController`.

So it is clearly "possible" to push a `UITabBarController` onto a `UINavigationController`'s stack, but why does the documentation state that this "cannot" be done, and what are the pitfalls of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

i have already provided one solution in the following link.Kindly check it once.
[How do you Show tabbar after Signup or login iOS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25255890/how-do-you-show-tabbar-after-signup-or-login-ios7/25256228#25256228).

Comment: Yes, I know that this is possible. My question is: why does the Apple documentation state that it cannot be done, and what are the pitfalls (if any) of this approach?